# Best Practise of injecting applicationContext in Spring3

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-3, applicationcontext

As in the title above, I am confused about pros cons between injecting applicationContext by directly @Autowired annnotation or implementing ApplicationContextAware interface in a singleton spring bean.

Which one do you prefer in which cases and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, both are bad. Both of them tie your application to the Spring framework, thus inverting the whole inversion-of-control concept. In an ideal world, your application should not be aware of being managed by an ApplicationContext at all.

Once you have chosen to violate this principle, it doesn't really matter how you do it. `ApplicationContextAware` is the legacy version that has been around [at least since Version 2.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.0/api/index.html?org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html). `@Autowired` is a newer mechanism but they work in pretty much the same way. I'd probably go with `ApplicationContextAware`, because it semantically makes clear what it is about.

Comment: Thanks. But what if the bean, which applicationContext is being injected into it, is already a spring bean? Do you think it is still a violation? Btw, actually approximately most of beans I have are a spring bean in my application, that's why I am just a bit confused about your mention: 'tie your application to the Spring framework'. Is it right in all cases or in the case only if I have an application which is partially seperated from spring framework and I use spring just only for some beans to achive some functionalities?

Comment: That depends on what you call a Spring Bean. If you have plain Java Beans that are managed by Spring from the outside, your application is not tied to Spring and it would probably take you less than a day to switch to a different IOC Container. That's one extreme (which, granted, you'll hardly ever find), the other extreme is what you are describing: dependency injection via Service Locator, or as I call it: Inversion of Inversion of Control. Just try and do that only when you actually must.

Comment: The major reason relavent to my question is injecting a prototype scoped bean into a singleton scoped bean. That's why I must get the bean from applicationContext (or BeanFactory) for each method calling. Btw, every class under my root package (it means all classes) are under the spring control. So the last question, can you explain more in detail of you mention: 'it semantically makes clear what it is about.'? Thanks you so much in advance again.

Comment: The name says it: the class is aware of the ApplicationContext, which violates the principle of IOC. Expressivele mentioning that violation in the interface name seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: I would challenge the statement of IOC violation. Utilizing @Autowired or the ApplicationContext does not violate IOC, they are utilized to *achieve* IOC. On your comment of "tying yourself to spring", please offer insight into a proposed alternative of leveraging spring without "tying oneself" to it in your mind. I fail to see how this is even possible let alone what point you could possibly be trying to make. It feels like you're suggesting that any tool or technology one uses to abstract around that entirely. Do you also abstract around objects in the JDK to insulate from future change?

Comment: @Russ First: You are arguing against something I wrote 8 years ago.
I don't think that gives you much insight into how I do things today.
Second: A container should manage an application, not the other way around.
When the application interact with the container, you're introducing a circular dependency. That's sometimes necessary in the real world, but is clearly an architectural smell.

Comment: If asking to justify your own logic comes across argumentative, I can't help you. My first point is @Autowired is used ubiquitously in spring to create configurations that achieve IOC. IE, there is nothing anti-IOC about Autowired. My second point is asking you to explain how one can use spring without tying oneself to spring. Your point of this question being old is a valid one, however, i came across this article in research and others will also. The intent is to keep SO clear so as to help as many as possible in the future.

Comment: No, it's the "Do you also abstract around objects in the JDK to insulate from future change" part that comes across as argumentative. To your point: sure, you can see your IOC container as part of your core application, then everything you say is valid. Or you can see it as an external manager, which can potentially switched to something else (Guice, pure DI, EJB etc). If you have a clean architectural separation, such a migration takes weeks. Otherwise, it takes months or years.

Comment: To be clear: it's fine to have tight coupling. A framework like spring offers a lot of advanced functionality you can't get anywhere else. But the downside is: you are closing doors and making yourself completely dependent on a third party framework. There's no right answer, but as a guideline for working with 3rd party software in general, I recommend chapter 8 ("Boundaries") of Clean Code.

Answer (score 3):

As @Sean Patrick Floyd says, the need of ApplicationContext is often due to a bad design. But sometimes you have no other option. In those cases I prefer the use of @Autowired because is the way I inject all other properties. So, if I use @Autowired for injecting MyRepository, why can't I use it for ApplicationContext or any other Spring bean?

I use Spring interfaces only for those things I can't do with annotations, for example BeanNameAware.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get a prototype in a singleton then you can use method injection. Basically, you create an abstract method that returns the object you need and spring will return the prototype everytime you call that method. You define the "lookup-method" in your spring config. Here are some links:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection
http://java.dzone.com/articles/method-injection-spring

Answer (score 0):

Since you are **not extending any of the spring classes your application is always separated from the framework**. Most of the cases you will not wanted to inject the `ApplicationContext` as it, but will need to inject the beans defined in the `ApplicationContext`.

The best case is always to stick to the bare minimum, until and unless you have any specific requirement and this is very simple with spring.

So either,

1. Annotate your beans and `scan` them in `application context`, then use `@Autowire` to wire them up.
2. Use `application context` to wire your bean expediencies(old xml style configs). You can use  `@Autowire` with this approach also.

When you want to control the bean life cycle, you can read the API and customize it, but most of the time these general settings will do the job.

Here are some examples.

1. [Spring Auto-Wiring Beans with @Autowired annotation](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/)
2. [Spring Auto-Wiring Beans XML Style](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-in-xml/)
3. [Spring IoC container API Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I have enough knowledge on spring in terms of common cases and autowiring :) The major reason relavent to my question is the ability to inject a prototype scoped bean into a singleton scoped bean. In that case, just normal bean injection does not work as expected, so I should get bean from the applicationContext (or better BeanFactory) for each method calling.

Comment: "Since you are not extending any of the spring classes your application is always separated from the framework". This is not true. Just injecting the ApplicationContext ties the application to Spring. It won't compile if Spring isn't present

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `ApplicationContext` at all.

## ObjectFactory

If you need to use prototype scoped beans in a singleton bean, inject an `org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory`.
For example using constructor injection:

```
@Service
class MyClass {
    private ObjectFactory<MyDependency> myDependencyFactory;

    public MyClass(ObjectFactory<MyDependency> prototypeFactory) {
        myDependencyFactory = prototypeFactory;
    }

}
```

## Why

Now what's the benefit over using `ApplicationContext` ?
You can substitute this dependency (e.g. in a test) by simply passing a lambda (since `ObjectFactory` is a `@FunctionalInterface`) that returns a stubbed version of it.

While it is possible to stub the `ApplicationContext`, it is not clear in that case which beans will be looked up and need to be stubbed.