# How to get hold of Spring Application context in my web app in a Stand alone java program

Tags: java, spring

I have already a webapp which is having Spring application context defined in a web.xml. Also I have a stand alone program in the same Project which call a webservice and get a list of products and insert those values in a table. This Stand alone program is like a scheduler which executes in its particular time. 
My doubts are as follows.

1. Can I create an application context in my Stand alone program as below

   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
       new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/myConfig.xml");

or

1. How to get the already loaded application context in my web app.
2. can we have multiple application context created in a same project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Can I create an application context in my Stand alone program as below

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/myConfig.xml");

Yes, but make sure you do it only one.

2.can we have multiple application context created in a same project

yes, but it is not a good practise. So create ApplicationContext only once for you stand alone program (may be one for your web-application) and call the ApplicationContextProvider to get the existing ApplicationContext

The sample code to create the ApplicationContextProvider is given below with explanation.

Spring configuration

```
<bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="dell.harmony.service.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>
```

This will be invoked by spring container, when it first creates an applicationcontext and the applicationContext will be passed to the setter method (setApplicationContext) . we expose the application context by the getApplicationContext() so that other methods can use it.

```
package dell.harmony.service;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


/*
 * 
 * Utility Class to return the Spring ApplicationContext
 * 
 * 
 */
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationContextProvider.class);

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0)
            throws BeansException {
        if (arg0 != null) {
            ctx=arg0;
        }
    }

    public synchronized static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
        if (ctx==null) {
            logger.info("Getting the context again as it is null");
            ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringModule.xml");
        }
        return ctx;
    }

}
```

When ever you need the application context, use it as follows

First Time when scheduler is initialized.

```
logger.info("Spring Application Context !!");
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/SpringModule.xml");
logger.info("Spring Application Context - End !!");
```

In all other places, use as follows:

```
ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext(); 
SingleDataLoader dl = (SingleDataLoader) context.getBean("singledataloaderdao");
```

Comment: Instead of doing a lookup simply inject the ApplicationContext where you need it. Add a field and annotate with one of `@Autowired`\`@Inject`\`@Resource`. No need for a provider and clutter your code with lookups.

Comment: Agreed, injecting applcationcontext using annotation is a good idea.

Comment: @M. Deinum  as per this thread, it is not a good idea to use annotation, i'm confused :)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657961/best-practise-of-injecting-applicationcontext-in-spring3

Comment: Well actually both are bad, as also mentioned in that thread. IN general you shouldn't be accessing the `ApplicationContext` directly. As soon as you start to need that (other then in infrastructure code) you should take a couple of steps back and rethink the design.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you can create your context by loading the file

```
ApplicationContext context = null;
        try {
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:config"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"applicationContext.xml");
} catch (Throwable e){
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
            logger.trace(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

Please note that the classpath: refears to your /src directory in case of stand alone program (while for webapp is your docroot).

You can have how many application context you want, and you can configure spring to load witch ones you need in your web.xml (or in your Main.class)